# Ansible looping

Tags: loops, ansible

I have the following variables:

```
vars:
  rows:
    - alpha
    - beta
    - gamma
  cols:
    - one
    - two
    - three
```

I've figured out how to (with this site's help) use back-references and how to combine a cartesian product, which I'm doing in other tasks, but now I need to do a "double loop" that ends up giving me the following sequence of items to work with:

```
Start -> alpha-one -> alpha-two -> alpha-three
Start -> beta-one -> beta-two -> beta-three
Start -> gamma-one -> gamma-two -> gamma-three
```

(The arrows are for illustrative purposes only.)

I can get the 'Start' string using a `default` filter and I understand how both basic loops and `include_tasks` can be used to loop, but I'm not understanding how to "restart" the inner loop within Ansible or how to loop within a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated** answer  (hope i got it right :) ):

i would use an `include_tasks` that will iterate the `rows` list, and in the included tasks file, i would have 1 task for the "start" and a 2nd task with a loop for the `cols` list:

PB:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    rows:
    - alpha
    - beta
    - gamma
    cols:
    - one
    - two
    - three

  tasks:
  - name: Loop include tasks
    include_tasks: test2.yml
    with_items:
    - "{{ rows }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: rowsval
```

test2.yml:

```
---
- name: Start task
  debug:
    msg: "Start iteration"

- name: Loop task
  debug:
    msg: "processing now: {{ rowsval }} with: {{ item }}"
  with_items:
  - "{{ cols }}"
```

hope it helps.

Comment: This is easy enough, yes, but it doesn't let me look back to a 'Start' point at beta-one and gamma-one.

Comment: not sure i understand the "start" iteration. perhaps an `include_tasks` that has 1 task as "start" (i.e. no variables) and then a task in loop that executes with: `alpha-one` then `alpha-two` and then `alpha-three`? and then iterate this `include_tasks` for all elements in the `rows` list?

Comment: Yes - I have an include task that uses "start" and "alpha-one", then uses "alpha-one" and "alpha-two", then "alpha-two" and "alpha-three". Then it should restart the inner loop - using "start" and "beta-one". That's the part I'm having trouble figuring out.

Comment: That got me to where I needed to be. Thank you!